# Lottery Payout Fun

Tags: percentages, ratio

I'm working on a lottery pay out mechanic for a game, and I'm not quite sure how to address multiple winners. The plan is that the players will always split the lottery earnings, but there are actually two brackets for pay out. There is the 50/50 split for matching three numbers, and a 90% Jackpot for matching all four. Assuming there is only one winning ticket for both the 90% Jackpot and the 50/50 split, what is the best way to formulate an equation that ensures that the Jackpot winner gets 90% of the payout? Closest I came with my pseudo-math is 72/27 split (of the total earnings...)

Comment: The standard terminology for "brackets for pay out" is "division" and payout going to a particular player is "dividend".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure the Jackpot winner gets $90\%$ of the payout, you pay it to him. That leaves $10\%$ for everybody else, so you can't pay anybody else more than that.  I don't understand what you mean by a $50/50$ split for three numbers, but it can't be more than $10\%$.

It sounds like you have not thought clearly about what you want.  One choice is to have a fixed prize pool for each drawing and have rules to allocate it.  In that case you cannot guarantee a specific prize for picking a certain set of numbers, because you might exceed the prize pool depending on how many people pick the right numbers.  The other choice is to guarantee a specific prize for each number of correct choices.  In that case you may go over budget on a specific draw, but if you have chosen the prize values correctly you will do fine in the long run.  Which do you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The prize pool is dynamically increasing As more tickets are purchased. As designed, the lottery a "normal lottery" with relative good odds of hitting all three numbers that awards 50% of the pool, and an additional harder "jackpot number that awards 90% of the pool. As long as there is only one winner its not a problem, but I guess I'm trying to find the best way to split up the prize pool in the likely event that any jackpot lottery winner will have to share the dividend with a normal lottery winner. Obviously the answer can't be to let the payout exceed what the lot

Comment: You also need to address other multiple winners, like five people each getting three numbers.  You could just give nine points to anybody who gets four and five points to anybody who gets three.  Then award the prize pool in proportion to each person's share of the points.  In that case if there were one person with four and two with three, the person with four would get $9/19$ and the two with three would get $5/19$ each.  You probably want the number of points more disparate than this.

Comment: Thank you all for contiributing you answers. I've decided what make since to me (as the lottery is set up) is to split the 90% into two parts (50+40), where the first 50 is divided equally with all 50% payout "normal" winners and the additional 40 is divided equally with all jackpot winners (jackpot winners still get their portion of the dividend from the 50% payout as well...)